# How to gradually accelerate a camera dolly-out animation from extreme closeup?

Tags: animation, camera

I want to animate a scene where the camera slowly dollies away from an extreme closeup of subject. In this case, I'm starting with a closeup on a tree frog on a branch and dollying away until the entire tree is contained in the frame.

The issue is if the camera dolly motion is constant (linear) along its path, then the impression is that the initial camera movement appears to be quick, and then appears to slow down as it moves further away; I want the camera motion to appear more constant.

I think the solution would be to slowly accelerate the camera's motion as it dollies out so that at the start of the animation the camera is moving slowly, and by the end is moving more quickly. Smooth acceleration along the camera's path is what I want, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.0, Window 11

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd have thought that you could do that easily with the Graph Editor in Blender.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Hovering over the graph editor and pressing 'T' will give you some options which might be useful.